# error rc1106 even using the latest sdk

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, sdk, fatal-error

I made an application it gives me an error like

`RC : fatal error RC1106: invalid option: -ologo`
Although i have installed the latest win sdk 7.0.
What i might be missing?Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `/nologo`, just fix it in project properties.

Comment: and hth .-Alf  can u tell in detail

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem. I fixed this by go to project property -> Resources -> General and set **"Suppress Startup Banner"** to **"No"**